# Hybrid event push-notification for IOS seems like not yet handled on mobilefirst 7.1

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Trying to handle notification on an hybrid application. The notification arrives on device (can see it in logs and on device when application closed) but there's no way to handle it by that code:

```
WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
    "myPush",
    "PushAdapter",
    "PushEventSource",
    function (props, payload) {
        console.log("received notification - in notifications.js")
        alert("moo");
    }
);
console.log("registered event source");
```

When watching mfp plugin, seems like iOS part missing, how can i handle that notification anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I am understanding, you are saying the issue is that the push notification arrives on device only when app is in background, but when app is in foreground app will not be pushed. And this is only happening for iOS?

Try using this sample to do a simple push in an MFP Cordova application and see if you are still experiencing the same issue.
https://github.com/csantanapr/mfp-push-template

Should be pretty simple to setup for iOS. Need to get p12 file, configure XCode to sign with correct profile, set p12 password in app descriptor, set app id in push adapter.

Helpful guide that you've probably used: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/

Comment: You understand well. For the test with sample, i already think about that, but right now i'm not allowed to spend more time on it (and handling all the certificates stuffs can take a lot, ...), will see that later.sorry. For the guide : true i used this one (BTW, the link "Setting Up Google Play Services" let you lost somewhere in a google doc to activate that service in NATIVE app, not hybrid, and don't know where to copy that stuff need to copy...)

Comment: Ok, with that code : 
        WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
          "myPush",
          "PushAdapter",
          "PushEventSource",
          function (props, payload) {
            alert("moo");
          });

          console.log("registerED event source");

          WL.Client.Push.onMessage = function (props, payload) {
            console.log("received message - on message - in notifications.js");
            alert("meeeee");
          };
My iphone meeeee but not moo

Comment: seems like WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback not working but WL.Client.Push.onMessage to the job

Answer (score 0):

Edit: if you are developing a *Cordova* application, then after configuring push notifications for iOS in the application, the implementation itself is still the same, as is for Classic Hybrid applications - as shown below.

For this matter you could also just take the Hybrid sample and follow the migration guide to have it running in a Cordova app (sans the setup, which is slightly different).

- Setup: http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_iOS.html
- Migration: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/14/converting-a-mobilefirst-hybrid-application-to-a-cordova-application/

---

Take a look at main.js: https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/EventSourceNotifications/blob/release71/apps/HybridEventSource/common/js/main.js

Specifically the following, which is the function where you handle the received notification once the application is brought to the foreground:

```
function pushNotificationReceived(props, payload) {
    alert("pushNotificationReceived invoked");
    alert("props :: " + JSON.stringify(props));
    alert("payload :: " + JSON.stringify(payload));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i've read readme.md and needed to confirm that fact. Do you know if/when push support in MFP Cordova applications will be available for IOS ?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. This is apparently supported. I've sent a note to the development team to gain more insight into it, however I do believe that once you have setup the project you still need to follow the same code as done in the same application - same APIs, same functions... So I suggest to the take the sample I mention in my answer and implement the same in your Cordova application.

Comment: My code quite looks the same. When application is off/backside, i recieve notification, but when the application is on/frontside, the handler isn't called (log at first line...) : Still not working, don't even know how to go further and what can help...